# Python - To remove a circle inside another circle when counting for an object

Tags: python, image-processing

I am right now working on a droplet generator and want to count the number of droplets it generates and the diameter of the the droplets. I am first converting the grayscale image into a binary image and extracting the features out of it and then starting to count the droplets. I am hereby attaching my image with this where you can see that the droplet is in the form of a circle with another circle inside it. So, my program is counting that as two droplets. But I don't want the circle inside the droplet to be counted as an object. Since I am new to python and OpenCV, i have tried quite a few searches and didn't find anything useful. It would be really nice if someone could help. I am adding the original picture. See if this might be useful to help.

Droplet image without the nozzle:

[image]

Extracted image:

[image]

Also the code is:

```
 image_subtracted = image-image_calibration
      if showImages == 1:
         print('image_subtracted')
         print(image_subtracted)
         fig3 = plt.figure(3)
         fig3.suptitle('pure subtracted image')
         plt.imshow(image_subtracted, cmap='Greys_r', interpolation='none')
        plt.draw()
        plt.waitforbuttonpress()


#1.3To precisely show only the droplet
image_subtracted[0:line_lowerNozzleEdge][:]=0

image_subtracted=image_subtracted[line_lowerNozzleEdge+1:][:]
image_subtracted=image_subtracted.astype('uint32')

image_tmp=image_subtracted
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)


image_tmp = ndimage.grey_erosion(image_tmp, size=(6,6));
image_tmp = ndimage.grey_dilation(image_tmp, size=(6,6))

image_subtracted=image_tmp

if showImages == 1:
  print('max(image_subtracted) = '+str(np.max(image_subtracted)))
  fig4 = plt.figure(4)
  fig4.suptitle('subtracted image')
  plt.imshow(image_subtracted, cmap='Greys_r')
  plt.draw()
  plt.waitforbuttonpress()
  plt.pause(0.5)


 #2.BINARIZE THE IMAGE


 thresh_rc = mh.thresholding.rc(image_subtracted) #Hmm!

 thresh_median = np.median(image_subtracted)

 thresh=thresh_rc

 image_binary = image_subtracted > thresh

 image_bin_int=image_binary.astype('uint8')

 if showImages == 1:
    print('mh-tresholding: '+str(thresh_rc))
    print('median tresholding: '+str(thresh_median))
    print('used tresh: '+str(thresh))
    fig6 = plt.figure(6)
    fig6.suptitle('binary image')
    fig6 = plt.figure(6)
    plt.imshow(image_binary, cmap=plt.cm.gray, interpolation='none')
    plt.draw()
    plt.waitforbuttonpress()

  #3.EXTRACT THE FEATURES
  image_tmp=image_bin_int
  image_tmp = ndimage.grey_erosion(image_tmp, size=(6,6));
  image_tmp = ndimage.grey_dilation(image_tmp, size=(10,10))
  image_extracted=image_tmp
  if showImages == 1:
     fig7 = plt.figure(7)
     plt.clf()
     fig7.suptitle('image extracted')
     plt.imshow(image_extracted, cmap=plt.cm.gray, interpolation='none')
     plt.draw()
     plt.waitforbuttonpress()



T = mh.thresholding.otsu(image_extracted.astype('uint8'))
labeled,nr_objects = mh.label(image_extracted.astype('uint8') > T)
print('number of detected objects = '+str(nr_objects))
label_array=np.array(labeled).ravel() 
label_array=np.sort(label_array)      
pixel_sum=np.zeros(nr_objects+1)

for ii in range(1,nr_objects+1,1): 
    n_tmp=np.where(label_array==ii)[0]
    pixel_sum[ii]=len(n_tmp)

ObjectArea=pixel_sum*pixelArea
#assumption of a circle:
Radius=np.sqrt(ObjectArea/np.pi)
Diameter=2*Radius
print(' ')
print('object diameters in um ='+str(Diameter/1e-6))
print(' ')
print(' ')

if showImages == 1:
    fig9 = plt.figure(9)
    plt.clf()
    plt.imshow(labeled, cmap=plt.cm.gray,  interpolation='none')
    plt.draw()
    plt.waitforbuttonpress()

return Diameter
```

Comment: Once invert the image and count. I guess it is counting the white background and the inner white as two objects. Also, can you put the original image once? And also how are you extracting the features from binary ? That might help

Comment: Why is this tagged OpenCV when there are no OpenCV functions being used? Do you have OpenCV available to use?

Comment: I have added the original picture. Also, yeah I have OpenCV to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written in c++ but you can easily port it to python.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // read image
    Mat src = imread("image.png"),dst;

    // convert to gray
    cvtColor(src, dst, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    // binarize the image by thresholing
    threshold(dst, dst, 30, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

    // get erosion kernel size
    int morph_size = 3;
    Mat el = getStructuringElement( MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size( 4*morph_size + 1, 2*morph_size+1 ));

    // erode image to fill the empty gaps and make it more connected
    erode(dst, dst, el);

    // holds the contour points of all the objects in the image
    std::vector<std::vector<Point> > v;
    // holds the heirarchy
    std::vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    // find contours
    findContours(dst, v, hierarchy, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

    std::cout<<"Number of shapes:" <<v.size()<<std::endl;

    // draw the contours back to original image
    drawContours(src, v, 1, Scalar(0,255,0),3,8, hierarchy, 0, Point());

    namedWindow("result");
    imshow("result", src);
    waitKey(0);
}
```

Binary image:

[image]

Contours drawn on original image:

[image]